# Android MVVM testing with Mockito, mock repository.observeValue() has problem

Tags: android, mvvm, mockito, android-livedata, android-testing

I'm trying to test MVVM with Mockito.
The architecture of MVVM is similar to [Android architecture blueprints](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples).

We observe data from repository as LiveData.
And try to test observed value like below code.

```kotlin
class SplashViewModel(
    private val appRepository: AppRepository
) {
    val appInfo: LiveData<AppInfo> = appRepository.observeAppInfo()
}

@Test
fun getAppInfo() {
    `when`(appRepository.observeAppInfo())
        .thenReturn(appInfoData)

    assertEquals(appInfoData, viewModel.appInfo.getOrAwaitValue())
}
```

The crucial point is `viewModel.appInfo` returns null, despite of I used mockito.

#### The problem

The creation of ViewModel is faster than using mockito.
So appInfo property is initialized with null, cause it dosen't know what `observeAppInfo()` is.

#### First solution

At first, I just trying to solve this problem with custom getter. Like this.

```
class SplashViewModel(
    private val appRepository: AppRepository
) {
    val appInfo: LiveData<AppInfo> get() = appRepository.observeAppInfo()
}
```

Now every time I access to appInfo they just re evaluate the data.
But is has it's own problem.

In this situation appVersion is getting error.

```
val appVersion: LiveData<String> = appInfo.map { 
    ...
}
```

So every transformation LiveData(Like Transformations, MediatorLiveData) must use custom getter too.
And I felt it's not a great solution.

How do you think of it?

Comment: What is `appInfoData` you return from `AppRepository` mock?

Comment: @AhmedMostafa It's just a fake data, that I create at the test class.

Comment: What is the type of `appInfoData` -> `LiveData<AppInfo>` or `AppInfo`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `@BeforeClass` to make sure your initialisation is run before the tests.

```
@BeforeClass
fun setup(){
   appInfo = appRepository.observeAppInfo()
}
```

[See more](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-before-beforeclass-beforeeach-beforeall#beforeclass)